# add .txt email attachament from memory in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, email

I want to send an email to a user containing a report in .txt format about changes made in a database.

The file will look like:

```
User     |   Acces   | Way_of_assignment | Project
---------------------------------------------------
uid3434     direct         group            x1
uid4453     indirect       direct           x2
```

But I want to create this attachament exclusively in memory. 
How do I do this?

Comment: I assume you have already looked at the [smtpClient class]( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx)?

Comment: Yes, I have everything in place, just need to add the attachment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a string in memory that represents your file.

Then, read it into a [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx), using the [`Encoding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx) classes to convert the string to bytes - this can be passed in to the [`Attachment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.aspx) constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the info, did some reading about this and I am on the right track! I`ll leave this open for a bit in case I have a followup question.